# What does the memory address mean?

Tags: memory, computer-science, byte

Does a hex memory address represent the position in the memory as a whole?

e.g. 4 gb ram and there is a memory adress. Does it point to the position(in bytes) that the data starts at? e.g. at 2.1 gb.

How do memory address work on hard disk before the data is loaded into memory?

Is there ever a case where parts of the data are fetched from memory and other data is fetched from disk? How are the locations differentiated?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hex memory address (like what you would see if you printed out the value of a pointer) points to a location in virtual memory.

On a 32 bit system, each process has a full 4GB of virtual memory.  This virtual memory is managed by the CPU and the operating system.  When you access a location in virtual memory, the CPU and operating system determine where in the systems actual physical memory that location is mapped, and the data is retrieved from there.

The operating system may also take things out of physical memory and swap them to disk, in order to make room in physical memory for other things.  Then, if you try to access the virtual memory location of something that was swapped from physical memory to disk, a "page fault" is generated which causes the OS to re-load the page from disk into physical memory.

Comment: Thanks. So is the virtual memory stored on disk or in memory?

Comment: @aljaree virtual memory is "virtual", non-existent. It isn't stored anywhere. In any specific moment it can be mapped to a physical RAM location, to address in swap, to address in `mmap`-ed file, etc. And the interesting case is that when some virtual memory address *isn't* mapped anywhere at all and you are trying to access it. In this case Access Violation a.k.a. Segmentation Fault errors are generated.

Comment: I am a little confused now. I am looking at it from a programmer point of view. If one had to write assembly, where would virtual memory come in? Does the word virtual in virtual machine have the same concept as virtual memory? Best book on virtual memory? Thanks

Comment: No, virtual machines have nothing common with virtual memory concept, except the word. As a programmer, you ask the OS for *associating* some virtual pages with real storage, via allocating segments in your executable image. The OS executable loader will then do the work, making stack and heap segments usable. Both these regions can be expanded later.

Comment: Would you recommend using a disassembler to learn more about this? Also, what memory address are presented in the disassembler? The physical memory addresses? How does virtual memory relate to this? Thanks.

Comment: @alJaree - You will only ever be concerned with Virtual Memory addresses.  As a programmer, unless you are writing an operating system, you should never have any visibility at all to actual "physical memory".

Comment: What about C on micro-controllers?

Comment: @alJaree - Sorry, yes, in that case you may be, or if you are writing code for a CPU that does not support virtual memory.  I was thinking more in terms of development on typical PC class computers.

Comment: I should have put in in my original question. but learnt somethings. Could you recommend a good book on virtual memory? Thanks

Comment: @alJaree - The Wikipedia article is pretty good.  If you really want a book, I would recommend this one: http://www.amazon.com/Operating-System-Concepts-Abraham-Silberschatz/dp/0470128720/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1295373808&sr=1-1

Answer (score 2):

Modern operating systems have [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

This means that the address which uses your program to access some byte in memory, is purely "virtual", non-existent. The operating system maps it via special hardware controllers to *real* memory locations which are completely different and there may be no physical memory location at all for a given address. For example, you may [mmap()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) a file into (virtual) memory, and accessing a byte at the virtual addresses would mean accessing a byte of *file*. Similarly, if some [memory page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_%28computer_memory%29) wasn't used for a long time, the OS may [swap off](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) the page from physical RAM to disk. In this case virtual memory wouldn't point to physical memory locations too.

Comment: @aljaree I think the policies of coping with virtual memory are somewhat OS-specific. What exact situation are you interested in?

Comment: @mitch-wheat Yeah, I didn't read it before posting (because I am familiar with virtual memory concept). Bad thing the article is in so poor state. `:/`

Answer (score 0):

In most cases - yes. But some processors uses 2 values to calculate real address. For example Intel 8086. 
Hardisk is only storage, that has its own system to store information. So before any CPU operation is executed, data has to be loaded into RAM.

Comment: Thanks. So when computers had minimal memory a while back, what if data amounting to more than the available memory were needed? I mean, live bytes resulting in more than the system provided with no memory available to release. They had to wait for new hardware?

Comment: Well, virtual memory system helps a bit. But if your application is memory intensive, the system can realy end up swapping. I would recomend to verify how many pages swapped out. Use task manager in Windows to find out.

Comment: No, I have no clue about this stuff yet. I am interested and just wondered about this question. thanks.